# When bulk inserting records, Temp Tables doesnt delete after operation ends and Insert fails at 3rd temp table

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, bulkinsert

[image]

First Tempdata Has 352.000 records 2nd has 146.000 and third one has 232.000 records.

This is the situation.Heres the code thats executing this.

```
            while (true)
            {
                var result = carDatabaseClient.GetInvoiceLines(authorizedService, authorizedService.LastInvoiceLineUpdate, lastId);

                if (result != null)
                {
                    if (result.Rows.Count != 0)
                    {
                        var dataRows = Functions.Convert<InvoiceLine>(result).Select(s =>
                        {
                            s.Id = authorizedService.Id + "-" + s.DcId;
                            s.AuthorizedServiceId = authorizedService.Id;
                            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.InvoiceId)) s.InvoiceId = authorizedService.Id.ToString() + "-" + s.InvoiceId;
                            return s;
                        }).ToList();

                        invoiceLineService.SaveOrUpdateRange(dataRows);
                        documentsTotal += dataRows.Count;
                        lastId = dataRows.LastOrDefault()?.DcId;
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    }
                    else
                        break;
                }
                else
                    break;
            }
```

Every query saves 500.000 records.
And while repeat around 3 times. And First 2 while loop saves properly, but last while loop gets stuck in temp tables and doesnt save whatever records left for 3rd loop.

And here is the saveOrUpdateRange method.

```
    public void AddOrUpdateRange(IList<T> entities)
    {
        Context.Database.SetCommandTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
        Context.BulkInsertOrUpdate(entities);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

BulkInsertOrUpdate uses EFCore.Bulkextensions nuget.

Heres my service scopes.

```
        services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
        //services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")).UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking));
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        //services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddScoped(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Memory usage? More information please!

Comment: I dont see any error logs anywhere but sql server doesnt delete those temp tables. And they are not saved to main table

Comment: But why should it.  Where does your code delete them. Where do you dispose your context?  You are not showing the relevant sections of your code

Comment: I am using generic and ıgeneric repository pattern. I dont have idisposable as method in any of generic classes.Shouldnt bulk update delete temp tables after its job is done. Edited my answer to show service configuration

Comment: Looking at the code the temp table should be dropped after the operation is completed unless UseTempDb is specified https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions/blob/master/EFCore.BulkExtensions/SqlBulkOperation.cs